# Why is my character flying off randomly Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm making a third person game and when I try to makie the character (cube) face the way the players mouse is pointing my character just goes flying off even though I didn't use W, A, S or D?

```
public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    
    public Vector3 CamPosition;
    
    public Transform PlayerBody;
   
    public float MouseSensitivity = 100f;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float MouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * MouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float MouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * MouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        
        PlayerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * MouseX);
       
        transform.position = player.position + CamPosition;
     }
}
```

Comment: With ```player.position + CamPosition```, what would ```CamPosition``` represent?

Comment: its a vector3 that will show where the camera position will be when following the player.

Comment: so the transform position will be the sum of both positions.   How does the change in the transform.position affect the playerbody?

Comment: It follows the player around?

Answer (score 0):

Did you attach it to the player or the cam?

See if you have a rigidbody attached to the player, it may be buggy due to the way they work in relation with transforms.

Try to mark the line that rotates the player. I believe it's somewhere else that causes the problem because there is nothing in there that moves the player.

Reply me if you found anything that affects the movement.